# Inserting data into MSSQL from Matlab

Tags: sql-server, matlab

I am trying to insert data into MSSQL through matlab and i am unable to pass the string values to the table.Here is my code:

```
username = get(handles.edit1,'String'); %edit1 being Tag of ur edit box
password= get(handles.edit2,'String'); %edit1 being Tag of ur edit box
confirm_pass = get(handles.edit3,'String'); %edit1 being Tag of ur edit box
email = get(handles.edit4,'String'); %edit1 being Tag of ur edit box
import System.Data.SqlClient.*
NET.addAssembly('System.Data');
conn = SqlConnection('Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Ear;Integrated Security=true;');
conn.Open();
cmd = SqlCommand('insert into Register(username,password,confirm_pass,email) values(@username,2,2,4)', conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue('@username', username.Value);
r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
r.Close()
conn.Close()
```

I am able to execute the code if i pass the values directly as follows:

```
cmd = SqlCommand('insert into Register(username,password,confirm_pass,email) values(1,2,2,4)', conn);
```

Any help would be appreciated.Thank you!

**Edit:**

```
username = get(handles.edit1,'String'); %edit1 being Tag of ur edit box
password= get(handles.edit2,'String'); %edit1 being Tag of ur edit box
confirm_pass = get(handles.edit3,'String'); %edit1 being Tag of ur edit box
email = get(handles.edit4,'String'); %edit1 being Tag of ur edit box
import System.Data.SqlClient.*
NET.addAssembly('System.Data');
conn = SqlConnection('Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Ear;Integrated Security=true;');
conn.Open();
cmd = SqlCommand('insert into Register(username,password,confirm_pass,email) values(username,password,confirm_pass,email)', conn);
r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
r.Close()
conn.Close()
```

**This is my Error:**

Error using Register>pushbutton2_Callback (line 214)
Message: Invalid column name 'username'.

Invalid column name 'password'.

Invalid column name 'confirm_pass'.

Invalid column name 'email'.
Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
HelpLink:

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 96)
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in Register (line 42)
gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in
@(hObject,eventdata)Register('pushbutton2_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))

Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback

**Table:**
id           -int
username     -varchar(50)
password     -varchar(50)
confirm_passs-varchar(50)
email        -varchar(50)

Comment: Is there an error message that is returned by matlab when you try to use the username parameter?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have edited my question along with the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the values obtained from GUI through edittext is in cell format.So i converted it to the string and then the query is executed.

**Here is my answer:**

```
username = get(handles.edit1,'String'); %edit1 being Tag of ur edit box
password= get(handles.edit2,'String'); %edit1 being Tag of ur edit box
confirm_pass = get(handles.edit3,'String'); %edit1 being Tag of ur edit box
email = get(handles.edit4,'String'); %edit1 being Tag of ur edit box
username=username{1};
password=password{1};
confirm_pass=confirm_pass{1};
email=email{1};
import System.Data.SqlClient.*
NET.addAssembly('System.Data');
conn = SqlConnection('Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Ear;Integrated Security=true;');
conn.Open();
testpath='insert into Register(username,password,confirm_pass,email) values';
open='(''';
close=''')';
string1 = strcat(testpath,open,username);
string2 = strcat(string1,''',''',password);
string3 = strcat(string2,''',''',confirm_pass);
string4 = strcat(string3,''',''',email);
string5 = strcat(string4,close);
disp(string5);
cmd = SqlCommand(string5, conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

In `.NET`, you can use two different approaches to define the parameter values of an `SqlCommand`:

1. Through `Parameters.Add`, as follows:

> ```
> cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Products WHERE ID = @ID";
> cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
> cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = 10;
> ```

2. Through `Parameters.AddWithValue`, as follows:

> ```
> cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Products WHERE Name = @Name";
> cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "MyProduct");
> ```

The difference between the two approach is subtle, but very important.

`Add` makes everything explicit, but presents two major drawbacks:

- it requires more code and more efforts;
- one of its overloads ([this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dd8zze1(v=vs.110).aspx), to be exact), even if deprecated, can be very ambiguous.

`AddWithValue`, on the opposite, infers the type of the parameter from the paramater value and doesn't perform any kind of validation. The latter approach can potentially lead to incorrect conversions, especially if used within an environment that handles variable types in a different way (like `Matlab`).

Your code is not hard to understand, but you forgot to describe your database table structure and to mention any potential error or exception produced by the code execution. This forces me to guess what's wrong with your implementation:

1. The most probable reason has to be identified in what I explained above: `AddWithValue` (with its implicit types) used within a non `.NET` programming environment looks like a very dangerous combo to me.
2. The table fields you are referencing (`username`, `password`, `confirm_pass` and `email`) look like `VARCHAR` fields. Despite this fact, your insertion is based on numeric values. I know this should not represent a problem, since a numeric string can be assigned to a `VARCHAR` field, but I think that, in the first case (`VALUES (@username,2,2,4)`), something weird could be happening.
3. Although `get(handles.edit1,'String')` looks absolutely correct, I don't understand why you are passing `username.Value` to the `AddWithValue` call. Once `get(handles.edit1,'String')` is fired, your `username` variable should already contain the required value.

Comment: I am sorry ,i added "username.Value" as a mistake.It is actually "username" and as you said all  my fields are of datatype "varchar".i added the numeric strings just to check whether it is inserted in the appropriate table.

Comment: Nope.Actually the values obtained through GUI in username and other variables are in cell format.So i converted it to string and then passed to the query.The query has been executed successfully now.Thank you for your kind effort.God bless you!!

Comment: Aaaah this is something I didn't think about. Nice to hear anyway. On a side note, in your code you can replace `ExecuteReader` with `ExecuteNonQuery` since it's an insertion and it seems like you are not using the `SqlDataReader` instance returned by `ExecuteReader`.

Comment: Yes.i changed it and answered my question.Thanks alot.

Comment: Fine... but you shouldn't quote your variables manually. Try to use parametrized queries in order to avoid unexpected results and to avoid exposing your application to SQL injection. Parameters are handled by the underlying code, which also automatically quotes them properly. Wrapping them into a .NET String instance should do the trick if you prefer to use AddWithValue.

Comment: Surely i will try to optimize my code as much as possible. Thank you